# How to get current year , previous years and next years after click on button In android kotlin which will also work fine in under android version 8

Tags: android, kotlin, date, year2038

I want to get next 5 years after from now and i am using this below code . It work fine in above android version 8 device  .

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun getCalculatedYear(date: String, month: Int): String? {
    val ld = LocalDate.parse(date)
    val currentMonth = ld.minusYears(month.toLong())
    Timber.tag("currentMonth").d(currentMonth.toString())
    var dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val newDate = dateFormat.parse(currentMonth.toString())
    dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
    return dateFormat.format(newDate!!)
}
```

Is there any solution to get this in all android version device.

> **Edited**
>
> **Found solution with below code**

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun getCalculatedYears( year: Int): String? {
    val c: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -year)
    val sdfr = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
    return sdfr.format(c.time).toString()
}
```

Comment: Try this you will get more flexible outputs https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Java 8+` `APIs` like `Time Date API` in Android 8 and below, by enabling `coreLibraryDesugaring`

To enable `API desugaring`

In your module level `build.gradle`, add `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true` to `compileOptions`

```
android {
    //..

    compileOptions {
            coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true

            //..
        }

    //..
}
```

Now add `coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5"` to `dependencies` of the same `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5"
    //..
}
```

---

> I want to get next 5 years after from now and i am using this below code

I didn't quite understand, how you're able to add 5 years to the passed date using your code, but you can easily do it using `Time Date` API like this

```
fun addYears(date: String): String? {
    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    var ld = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter)
    ld = ld.plusYears(5L)
    return ld.year.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this helps me to find previous and next years

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun getCalculatedYears( year: Int): String? {
    val c: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    val sdfr = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
    return sdfr.format(c.time).toString()
}
```